# How to update parent record when I update or insert child record, via trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new in salesforce developer. Trying to create trigger.

I have 3 objects.

1. Student
2. Books
3. Book Assignments

On Book Assignments object I created Master Detail relationship with Book and created lookup for Student object.

Now, when I assign new book to any of the student, count of Book should update on student object. To count the book on student object , I created one number field on Student object with name of Number.

Comment: Why didn't you make Book Assignment master-detail to the Student? That would give you automatic roll-up capabilities. Or, why not use [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) so you don't have to build it yourself? Also, have you [searched for existing solutions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=rollup+trigger+insert+update+delete+undelete)? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Actually, I want to learn ' How to use After Insert" trigger. I confuse to take id of parent object, how to get it. If you can provide the code for this, it will be helpfull

Comment: Okay, did you look at something like [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/60403) or perhaps [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/59989)? There's lots of examples already here on SFSE for you to look at.

Comment: Yes, I have seen when the account is created automatically opportunity and contact is created. This type of example i have seen. But facing an issue when I am implementing my own

Comment: Okay, well, let's see what you've tried so far. Maybe we can help you. Click **[edit]** and add in your code. It doesn't matter that it doesn't work, just show us what you've done so far.

Comment: trigger t1 on Book_Assignment__c (after insert) {
Student__c S1 = new Student__c();
for(Book_Assignment__c b : trigger.New)
{

if(b.Student1__c== S1.Name)
{
S1.BookName__c = b.Book__C;
}

update S1;
}
}  getting this error message:Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger t1 caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: t1: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []: Trigger.t1: line 15, column 1

Answer (score 0):

The S1 instance of student will always be empty and it will never be equal to to the Name of the student in your trigger context so the check you were doing will always fail.

You need to do couple things.

1. Get the student record Id’s if there is a student added in the book assignment and get those student records and do an update to student records.
2. As you have the student records and book assignment records handy you can update as you want.

Comment: Can you please write code for me, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Can anyone please help here?